# listview (2 lines) onclick: retrieve specific data from clicked item (can't access map-like object)

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I'm building a listview (with 2 lines for each item) from a database query. I'm attaching some data to each item, and I'm having trouble retrieving it again later in their onClick listeners.

**data** is a list of key/value pairs, let's say *Title, Date, and ID*

```
List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

my adapter to create the listview that looks like this:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            new String[] {"title", "date"},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
            itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I am attaching onListItemClick listeners like so:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, CtestActivity.class);
      Object obj = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
      // here I want to extract the id from obj
      // obj.toString() is {id:7, title: sometitle, date: yesterday}
}
```

This may simple be a lack of java knowledge. Either way, I'd appreciate some info on how to access specific values from this 'map-like' object obj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onListItemClick()` listener, simply convert the generic Object into your Map:

```
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
String id = map.get("id");
String title = map.get("title");
String date = map.get("date");
```